# How to access my Home PC from out side by WCF service

Tags: wcf

How can i create the proxy of wcf service which runs on my home pc from out side or from my office pc. when i connect my home pc to internet then ISP assign a dynamic IP to that pc. my home pc has no fixed or static IP.

if i know my Home pc dynamic IP then can i create the proxy of wcf service which is running on my home pc from my office pc. wcf client will run at my office pc and wcf service will run in my home pc.

so this is the situation.

it would be sufficient if anyone the dynamic ip of my home pc as a result one can reach to my wcf service. so please tell me what are the information one has to acquire to reach my wcf service running on my home pc.

please give me the idea how can i run wcf client at my office which can connect to wcf service running on my home pc and exchange some data. please give me the full instruction as a result my wcf client from my office pc which can connect to my wcf service running on my home pc.

some one told me to use a common way to solve this problem is to use a Dynamic DNS, such as No-IP http://www.noip.com/. he said "**DDNS services allow you to access your home computer using a fixed name, like yoursite.no-ip.org. It requires your home computer to run a small client program that communicates with the provider's servers to update the DNS records for your name whenever your IP address changes.**"

suppose i am not interested for No-IP http://www.noip.com/.

just give me the idea if i know the dynamic IP of machine where my wcf service is running then how can i connect my wcf client from office pc to wcf service which is running on my home pc having dynamic IP which is known to me. looking for good discussion. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 4 things correctly setup:

1. **Your local WCF service should be up and running**: Test it from your local pc and see that it works correctly.
2. **Your local Windows firewall have to allow connections to your port**: In order to test this you shoul try to connect to your WCF service from a different computer in your home.
3. **Your router have to redirect a given port to your local PC**: Probably port 8080 of your router to port 80 of your local PC. It is done from router configuration settings.
4. **Dynamic DNS correctly pointing to your home DSL**: Probably your DSL router will have a tab in configuration that allows it to connect to Dynamic DNS service. In order to test this check that your Dynamic DNS name resolves to your

**Advice**: A tiny virtual server in AWS (and maybe Azure) is free and maybe an interesting alternative...

Comment: thanks for your answer.i am very poor in networking so many thing is not clear from your answer. point 3 & 4 not clear. not clear u said port 8080 of your router to port 80 of your local PC. It is done from router configuration settings. please explain point 3 and 4 in more detials how to enable things and how test and be sure everything is working.

Comment: i am not familiar with the word Azure. so can you redirect me to few good article which can help me to know what is Azure in details and how to use it to deploy any service. please come with answer in details for the points 3 & 4. thanks

Comment: **Step 3**: Which router do you have? Check this link (http://www.dslreports.com/faq/7074) for an example on how to do it in a total different router. Google for yours. The idea is to choose an external port in your DSL (accessible by anyone in internet even me) and redirect it to port in your pc. In my example I was proposing external port 8080 with your internal port 80. External port can be any as long as is not used

Comment: **Step 4**: This is an optional step. If you don't set it up you should use your IP to connect. If your dsl provider changes your IP often you will find it annoying. In this case you setup a dynamic IP. Dynamic IP client can be installed in your windows machine. Some routers also have an embedded dynamic dns client.

Comment: Azure stands for **Azure Services Platform**. It is a cloud computing platform from Microsoft similar to Amazon AWS. Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform

Answer (score 0):

your wcf proxy that runs on your home pc, runs on a port. you will need to map that port from your router to your pc, so you can access it from outside. using No-Ip you can create a 'static' dns record that gets you to your pc

`Home.No-Ip.org:1234`

instead of using that, you could also just use your ip address, which is provided by your isp. note, if that is subject to change, you would need to update it everytime it changes.

assuming, you mapped port 1234 to your pc, and the correct port the wcf service is running on.

next you would need to get the client to know where the service is, so you would need to set the endpoint of the service there, the endpoint consists then of the `Home.No-Ip.org:1234/someEndPointName`

depending on firewall settings at your work place and your home network this should work, i do not, however, know what happens between the connection at home or work

Comment: i do not want to use No-Ip utility rather i would like to access my wcf service from my office. so guide me what step i need to follow up. thanks